# How do I add a value to button and attach a method to be run onclick?

Tags: magento

```
<delete_gamecode translate="label">
    <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
        <value>button</value>
```

So in my system.xml, I created a button, but it only shows a button with no text. How do I add a value to the button?

Also, I want the button to delete the game code as well. How can I do this?

Is there a way for me to attach JavaScript to these buttons so I can do some JavaScript confirmations? For example, after I click the button, it will say "Are you sure you want to delete this gamecode?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `<frontend_model>`. Please refer to following files for the example:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/System/Storage/Media/Synchronize.php
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/system/storage/media/synchronize.phtml
```

Comment: Wow, that took me a few hours to just get the button working. Is AJAX the ONLY way to associate an action method in PHP with the button?

Comment: Let's say, the only generic one.